# How to apply KMeans clustering on PDF Data using python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, text-mining, unsupervised-learning

With reference to this topic: [How to convert token list into wordnet lemma list using nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416780/how-to-convert-token-list-into-wordnet-lemma-list-using-nltk?noredirect=1#comment93710449_53416780)

I want to show the words with similar meaning in a cluster diagram. I went through some of the methods and found KMeans is a good start to learn. I am using tf-idf vectorizer to convert my pdf data to vectorized version but ended up getting this error:

```
ValueError: After pruning, no terms remain. Try a lower min_df or a higher max_df.
```

Here's my updated source code: (designed to work on any pdf data source)

```
import string
import re
import nltk
import PyPDF4
import plotly as py
import collections
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from pprint import pprint
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
# additional stopwords to be removed manually.
file = open('Corpus.txt', 'r')
moreStopwords = file.read().splitlines()
ps = nltk.PorterStemmer()
wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()

data = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(open('ReadyPlayerOne.pdf', 'rb'))
pageData = ''
for page in data.pages:
    pageData += page.extractText()


def clean_text(text):
    text = "".join([word.lower() for word in text if word not in string.punctuation])
    tokenize = re.split("\W+", text)
    text = [wn.lemmatize(word) for word in tokenize if word not in stopwords]
    final = [word for word in text if word not in moreStopwords]
    # Accessing wordnet synset corpora to find the meaning of the words.
    lemmas = []
    for token in final:
        lemmas += [synset.lemmas()[0].name() for synset in wordnet.synsets(token)]
    return list(set(lemmas))  # returns unique words
    # return list(lemmas)
    # return final


def cluster_texts(texts, cluster):
    # K-Means Clustering
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=clean_text,
                                 max_df=0.9,
                                 min_df=0.1)

    tfidf_model = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
    km_model = KMeans(n_clusters=cluster)
    km_model.fit(tfidf_model)
    clustering = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for idx, label in enumerate(km_model.labels_):
        clustering[label].append(idx)
    return clustering


filter_data = clean_text(pageData)
clusters = cluster_texts(filter_data, 3)
pprint(dict(clusters))
```

Comment: Hey Tony what exactly is the question here?

Comment: @MisterMonk I tried to cluster the data but I am getting the value error. Am I going on the right path?

Comment: Can you provide the error and where it happens

Comment: I mentioned the error text above the source code, i guess the error is occurring when the cluster_texts() method is invoked.

Comment: So have you done what the error message tells to do?

Comment: You can leave the parameters out at the beginning as writen in the docs. The Values for min_df is much to high i think. Don't take a float, better take a int for the count. The proportion depends on text size, an absolut value does not.

Comment: @Vivek No, I am wondering what would be an ideal fix for this problem.